# Row level security check with function name

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way add a row level security that allows inserts on a table (say logs) only when called from a specific trigger function.

I am using postgres by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with row level security, which is about imposing limitations at query planning time.

I think the best solution for that requirement is a `SECURITY DEFINER` trigger function. The end user doesn't get permissions on the log table, but there is a trigger function owned by a user who is allowed to insert into the log table. If the function is defined as `SECURITY DEFINER`, it will run with the permissions of the owner and will be able to insert into the log table.

Don't forget to set a safe `search_path` on the function.

Comment: Interesting. I will try that out.

Comment: Yes. It worked.I think I don't need search path as I just have a unique table name in public schema.
If I am wrong, please correct me. Will setting search path improve performance even in my case.

Comment: You are wrong. If you can create an object in the `search_path` of a `SECURITY DEFINER` function, you can usually [get superuser privileges](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).